# Jetbrains Compare Tool as a Standalone tool

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to use the diff tool that **Jetbrains** provides **(IntelliJ, TeamCity)** as a standalone tool.

Is that possible? where can I download it?

I have license for both **IntelliJ** and **TeamCity**.

Comment: I know this doesnt answer your question, but Beyond Compare is also quite good. Otherwise, could you find a way to utilise the code from IntelliJ community edition and build your own tool?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the one from TeamCity, but diff from IDEA can be used from the command line as [described in the documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/running-intellij-idea-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html).

If you are looking for the similar cross platform tool implemented in Java, try [SmartSynchronize](http://www.syntevo.com/smartsynchronize/).